# Will changing the Linux hostname of a Docker Swarm manager cause it to lose its Swarm Manager status?

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

If I change the Ubuntu hostname of a Docker Swarm node that serves as Manager node, will it cause other nodes to lose "trust" in it as a Manager?

Answer (score 2):

There might be options where this would work without breaking. However, I've seen $bad-things happen when people change hostnames or /etc/hosts in a running swarm. Especially as this is a swarm manager, I wouldn't try to do that.

What I would recommend:

- remove the manager from the swarm (you do run your swarm with 3, 5 or 7 managers, right?)
- change whatever you need to change
- rejoin the manager to the swarm